# EmbeddedChart and Adwords Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-ads-api

I'm trying to create a chart in a Google Spreadsheet using an Adwords Script (from the Adwords Platform). I used this code to make the chart:

```
var range2 = sheet.getRange("A1:C7");
ssNew.setActiveRange(range2);

var chart = sheet.newChart()
    .setPosition(5, 6, 5, 5)
    .setChartType(Charts.ChartType.COLUMN)
    .addRange(sheet.getActiveRange())
    .build();
sheet.insertChart(chart);
```

This code works when i run it from Script Editor but it doesn't when I run it from Adwords Script. An error ocurred:

> ReferenceError: "Charts" is not defined. (line XX)

Thank you

Comment: Hi, and welcome to Stack Overflow. Just to let you know, sentences like your "I will be very grateful..." are discouraged on SO - please don't be offended if it is removed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like Charts has now been added to AdWords Scripts, give it another shot!

Answer (score 0):

The Charts service is part of Google Apps Script, and when you are running code within the "Script Editor", you have access to all the services provided by that service.

The Adwords IDE looks similar, but does not have access to those services. That's why you see the error - there is no javascript library you can include that will give you direct access to your spreadsheet via the Apps Script Services.

However, you can use spreadsheets as a data source for your Adwords script through its [SpreadsheetApp interface](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/service_spreadsheet), so you could write the data you want in your spreadsheet chart from Adwords. The chart itself would be defined within the spreadsheet, of course.